# Moving up a directory using Node.js process.cwd()

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not sure if I have ever figured out a good workaround for this.

I am in a directory, I want to use process.cwd() to find the currently working directory but want to move up on directory, something like so:

```
var serverPath = path.resolve(process.cwd() + '../bin/www');
```

however, this obviously won't work, and will give me an error along these lines:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/ORESoftware/suman../bin/www'
```

so what is the best way to use process.cwd() and move up a directory?

Comment: and you did of course try `process.cwd() + '/../bin/www'`

Comment: Good comments from everyone identifying the problem. Also, you have the `__dirname` available to you from any module. It gives you the directory where the module exists. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need a `/` before the `..`:

```
var serverPath = path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/../bin/www');
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `\`.

You should consider calling `path.join(process.cwd(), '../bin/www');` before you pass it to `path.resolve`. This will help get the slashes correct. Concatenation of file paths is generally considered risky business.